# Creating a loop that chooses the option closest to an argument

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, arguments

Currently I'm trying to find out how to make a loop that will search through multiple options that is the closest to a argument.

In the image below valves, in column B, are shown with their size, column C. This information is listed in Sheet2.

[image]

On Sheet1, a selection is made depending on the limit of a certain speed, C3.
If the speed of the valve currently selected, Sheet1 A3, is too high. Then the user needs to select a different valve in the dropdown list on Sheet1 A1 till the value A3 is below the value of C3. See image below.

[image]

What I want to create is a loop that will search the for a valve which speed, A3, is just below the limit. So the first value that will be < C3. The code must then show in cell A1 which valve is the best option.

This is the code I have so far, but I have no idea how to continue this to get it working.

```
Sub Selectvalve()

Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer

x = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
y = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").Value

For Each cell In Worksheet("Sheet2").Range("C1:C9")
    If x < y Then

    Else

    End If

Next cell

End Sub
```

Additional information:
Sheet1:

A1 has cell name: "Valve_size"

A2 contains formula: '=VLOOKUP(Valve_size;Sheet2!$B$1:$C$9;2;FALSE)'

A3 contains formula: '=2*V_stroke_front/(PI()/4*DN_valve^2)*1000*spm/60'

A4 has cell name: "V_stroke_front"

A5 has cell name: "spm"

Comment: You don't need a loop for this, your data is already sorted so a simple `VLOOKUP` with the last argument set to `TRUE` will do the trick

Comment: @Macro Man, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. The "AP17" is not directly linked to the formula. Currently it is a input by the user. Could you please show an example? Or explain it a bit more?

Comment: I'm a bit lost - you keep referring to C1 and C3, but there's nothing in C1? Can you give an example like "If user inputs _x_ then this should return _y_" ?

Comment: My mistake... C1 should be A3.

Comment: So on sheet1, cell C3 (y) is a value that is given, it's what the value is allowed to be maximum in cell A3. The value of A3 depends on what the input is in cell A2, the value of A2 depends on what the user selects in A1. Currently the user has to manually achieve that the value of A3 < C3. Hope that this clears things up.

Comment: Sorry I got pulled away for work, if I get a few mins I'll take a look at this again for you.

Comment: @MacroMan, I think I've found a solution that doesn't need macro's probably. I've simply inverted the VLOOKUP. I put the formula that is in A3 in the column on Sheet2 in column D. So that it will calculate every speed. Then it will search which speed is closest to the limit. Then use VLOOKUP to link it to the right valve size.